# Choosing a statistical method for customer preferences

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, factor-analysis, discriminant-analysis

I have received a data set about the ingredients of sweets of different brands, as well as information about prices in percent, sugar and profit in percent. The information on the ingredients are dummy variables, where 0 means that the characteristic is not present and 1 means that it is present. The other variables are numerical and represent the sugar content of a candy, the price of a product and the profit per product. The goal is to select a statistical method to determine consumer preferences and to make a prognosis for a new product. I would like to implement the solution for this in R.

Using the columns winpercent (=profit per product) and pricepercent (price per product) I was able to determine the product with the highest profit and the lowest price. I also found out that the sugar content of the found product was very low. Furthermore I could see that the 3 products with the highest profit contained chocolate.

What kind of statistical methos would be suitable?

dpt(rbind(head(cbc.df, 10), tail(cbc.df, 10)))

```
dput(rbind(head(cbc.df, 10), tail(cbc.df, 10)))
structure(list(competitorname = c("100 Grand", "3 Musketeers", 
"One dime", "One quarter", "Air Heads", "Almond Joy", "Baby Ruth", 
"Boston Baked Beans", "Candy Corn", "Caramel Apple Pops", "Tootsie Roll Juniors", 
"Tootsie Roll Midgies", "Tootsie Roll Snack Bars", "Trolli Sour Bites", 
"Twix", "Twizzlers", "Warheads", "WelchÕs Fruit Snacks", "WertherÕs Original Caramel", 
"Whoppers"), chocolate = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), fruity = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), caramel = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), peanutyalmondy = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), nougat = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), crispedricewafer = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), hard = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), bar = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), pluribus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), sugarpercent = c(0.73199999, 
0.60399997, 0.011, 0.011, 0.90600002, 0.465, 0.60399997, 0.31299999, 
0.90600002, 0.60399997, 0.31299999, 0.17399999, 0.465, 0.31299999, 
0.546, 0.22, 0.093000002, 0.31299999, 0.186, 0.87199998), pricepercent = c(0.86000001, 
0.51099998, 0.116, 0.51099998, 0.51099998, 0.76700002, 0.76700002, 
0.51099998, 0.32499999, 0.32499999, 0.51099998, 0.011, 0.32499999, 
0.255, 0.90600002, 0.116, 0.116, 0.31299999, 0.26699999, 0.84799999
), winpercent = c("66.971.725", "67.602.936", "32.261.086", "46.116.505", 
"52.341.465", "50.347.546", "56.914.547", "23.417.824", "38.010.963", 
"34.517.681", "43.068.897", "45.736.748", "49.653.503", "47.173.229", 
"81.642.914", "45.466.282", "39.011.898", "44.375.519", "41.904.308", 
"49.524.113")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: *Conjoint analysis* usually refers to a type of designed experiment with customer level choices as the manipulated treatment. Your description of your data doesn't sound like it meets those requirements. There is a type of marketing model known as *revealed preferences* which should work with your data. Lee Cooper's classic, 1989 book, Market Share Analysis, is the single best introduction to this approach in the literature. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259583948_Market_Share_Analysis_Evaluating_Competitive_Marketing_Effectiveness

Comment: @ Mike Hunter thank you very much for pointing me to this statistical method and the book. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @ Mike Hunter I have read several chapters of your proposed book and found the ideal point of modeling. Could ideal point modeling be a suitable method to calculate the preference for a new product?

Comment: The use of ideal point models was dropped sometime in the 90s by most marketing scientists. They were deemed unrealistic. The key with Cooper's book is his structuring of panel data (pooled time series) model framework(s) which he develops with copious examples and SAS code for implementation. Also, his analysis of differing elasticities is very insightful. His final chapters on mapping cross-brand elasticities is interesting but not something picked up by others.